# How to port Chrome extension to Firefox addon?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I get this error in Firefox:

```
There was an error during the temporary add-on installation.
Error details ▼
File red_apples.zip does not contain a valid manifest
```

[This](https://github.com/GirkovArpa/red-apples) is the extension I'm trying to port.  Here's the manifest:

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Red Apples",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ]
  },
  "version": "0.0.0.2",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon16.png",
    "default_title": "Red Apples",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "script.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

At the bottom of [this](https://blog.chosunghyun.com/porting-a-chrome-extension-to-firefox-add-on/) tutorial it says there's a 99% chance it works without modification, if it passes the test [here](https://www.extensiontest.com/).  But it passes the test and still doesn't work.

I get the manifest error both for the version packed with Chrome, and for the version just compressed as `.zip`.

Comment: Maybe the files in zip are inside a directory? manifest.json must be at the top level of the archive, not inside a directory. You can also unzip everything and load it from disk directly.

Comment: I double-checked to make sure manifest.json is at the top level.

Comment: The error message is pretty unambiguous so you should either try loading an unpacked extension or recreate the archive. Also try resaving manifest.json in UTF-8 encoding.